# SyntaxError: illegal character when posting array to data attribute of highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have a rails app that uses highcharts to display a line graph of 2 currencies. However when I run the app on my browser I keep getting the following error in firebug

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
 data: #&lt;Forex::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xc743144&gt;
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my javascript code since it does not include the following after data attribute of highcharts

```
#&lt
```

Here is my code:

```
<div id="forex">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
  new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: "forex"
  },
  title: {
    text: "Forex"
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: "datetime"
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: "Shillings"
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat("%B %e, %Y", this.x) + ': ' +
        "$" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
    }
  },
  series: [
  <% { "Dollar" => Forex.dollar, "British Pound" => Forex.british_pound }.each do |name, value| %>
  {
    name: "<%= name %>",
    pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
    pointStart: <%= 3.weeks.ago.to_i * 1000 %>,
    data: <%= value %>
  },
  <% end %>
  ]
});
});
</script>
</div>
```

I'm populating my data from a scope defined on **forex.rb** which is as follows

```
scope :dollar, -> { where(:us_dollar != 0) }
scope :british_pound, -> { where(:british_pound != 0 ) }
```

I've done according to Santosh's answer:

```
<% { "Dollar" => Forex.dollar, "British Pound" => Forex.british_pound }.each do |name, value| %>
  <p><%= name == 'Dollar' ? a=value.pluck(:us_dollar) : b=value.pluck(:british_pound) %></p>
<% end %>
```

But this prints out 2 empty arrays while I have 2 values in my table attributes

us_dollar: 88.27 and british_pound: 149.23

Comment: try to change "$" to "\u0024"

Comment: can you send me a print about result of : <% { "Dollar" => Forex.dollar, "British Pound" => Forex.british_pound }.each do |name, value| %>

Comment: I think that may be the problem because printing value gives me ** #<Forex::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xc8034a8>

#<Forex::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xc803070>**

Comment: How do I get it to give me an actual field value though. My model has just 2 field attributes: us_dollar and british_pound which store the value of the kenyan currency compared to those currencies. I'm trying to output a line chart comparing the 2 values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scope syntax is wrong

Change the conditions to

```
where(["us_dollar != ?", 0])
```

Change the data to

```
data: <%= name == 'Dollar' ? value.pluck(:us_dollar) : value.pluck(:british_pound) %>
```

Comment: That return 2 empty arrays instead of 2 field values I have. Check my edit

Comment: First. My answer and your updated code is different. Secondly, do you have any data in your Forex model?

Comment: I was just trying to see if it prints out something since my graph did not have any data. My forex model has one row of data with these specific values us_dollar: 88.27 and british_pound: 149.23